# PHP function problem

Tags: php

I have a php function script that is supposed to uncheck a checkbox or checkboxes if a user unchecks it when the preview button is clicked but I can only get the last 
checkbox that was unchecked to stay unchecked but not the other checkeboxes how can I fix this so that all the checkboxes that where unchecked stay unchecked?

Here is part of my PHP function that is giving me the problem.

```
if(isset($_POST['preview'])){
    foreach($query_cat_id as $qci) {
        if(!in_array($qci, $cat_id)){
            $unchecked = $purifier->purify(strip_tags($qci));
        }
    }
}


for ($x = 0; $x < count($query_cat_id); $x++){
    if(($query_cat_id[$x] == $cat['id']) && ($cat['id'] != $delete_id) && ($cat['id'] != $unchecked)){
        echo 'checked="checked"';
    }
}
```

Comment: @codaddict, Not all my checkboxes stay unchecked when unchecked is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just just check if the variable is set, if the checkbox is checked when the form is submitted, it will be available in `$_POST['checkboxName']`, otherwise, `isset($_POST['checkboxName'])` will return false.

### Basic script to test it

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['heh']))
    echo $_POST['heh'];
else
    echo "Not checked";
?>
<form action='yourPage.php' method='post'>
<input type='checkbox' name='heh' />
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

### View it in action

http://robertsquared.com/so.php

Comment: I believed I tried this before but how can I integrate it into my code?

Comment: I'm not sure the overall functionally of what you're trying to achieve, just that you wanted to keep your checkboxes checked. Are you posting to the same file that submits like my example?

Comment: Not all my checkboxes stay unchecked when unchecked is the problem my script retrieves checkbox values from a database.

Comment: Alright, the `preview` had me thinking you were doing some sort of checking on form submit and you wanted to reproduce the checkbox's state. What are the values stored in the database for a checked checkbox vs an unchecked one?

Comment: The values that are stored in the database are all the checked checkboxes values from the last save to be displayed as a check in the checkboxes. And unchecked values are from a different table which displays all the checkboxes unchecked.

Comment: Right, but what's the actual value for a checked checkbox? Are you storing "on" for checked?

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem on client side

i have a input of type hidden with the same name as the checkbox with the value of 0 and the checkbox right after the hidden field with the value of 1

if the checkbox is not checked i get the value of 0 from the hidden field and if someone checks i got the 1 from the checkbox.

so i only need to check if $value==1 then checked=checked

Comment: Is there a better way to do this without using the hidden input tag.

Comment: i think there a lots of different ways, but for me, this is the simplest